# VBA - Color borders of a cell range white

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a cell look borderless by coloring the edges white. Here is my code and the goddarn thing does not work. Thanks for correcting it.

```
 Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(Worksheets("Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 15))
    With cel.Borders
        If .Item(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
            .Item(xlEdgeTop).Color = vbWhite
        End If

        If .Item(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
            .Item(xlEdgeBottom).Color = vbWhite
        End If
    End With
Next
```

** UPDATE **
Pictures attached if it helps.

I used this code from the link @Big Ben shared.

```
Private Sub TurnOffGridLines(target As Worksheet)
Dim view As WorksheetView
For Each view In target.Parent.Windows(1).SheetViews
    If view.Sheet.Name = target.Name Then
        view.DisplayGridlines = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

And I am calling that sub like this and it errors out. My worksheet name is "Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress"

```
TurnOffGridLines ("Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you expand on "does not work"? What happens? Nothing? You get an error message? etc...

Comment: Why don't you just hide the grid or am I missing something?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - No error message but the borders do not get white colored.

Comment: @BigBen - How do I hide the grid programmatically? I need grid for other worksheets in the book

Comment: `ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368373/how-can-i-turn-off-gridlines-in-excel-using-vba-without-using-activewindow

Comment: Can I use specific worksheet name instead of Active Window. I generally have an attention span of 3yo and I keep flipping between worksheets while the data is being loaded. And last I clocked, it took 6 whole seconds to load the worksheet in question. Thanks.

Comment: No because `DisplayGridlines` is the property of the `Window`, but see the link.

Comment: @BigBen - I sorta did. In a crunch for time right now but using ActiveWindow clearly means that focus must be on the window that I want to remove borders for? (DUH!?)

Comment: I don't necessarily think so based on a read of that question/answer, specifically the edit, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @BigBen - Please see my updated code block in my question.

Comment: You need to pass a worksheet *object* as the parameter, not a string.

Comment: I am lost, bud :( And I am sorry that my company's firewall is blocking the chat window. Otherwise, I would have preferred a quick chat.

Comment: To pass the worksheet: `TurnOffGridLines Worksheets("Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress")`

Comment: @BigBen yes, realized that 2 seconds after hitting Enter... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems like you are re-inventing functionality. I'd just hide the grid.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368373/how-can-i-turn-off-gridlines-in-excel-using-vba-without-using-activewindow), I would add the following:

```
Private Sub TurnOffGridLines(target As Worksheet)
    Dim view As WorksheetView
    For Each view In target.Parent.Windows(1).SheetViews
        If view.Sheet.Name = target.Name Then
            view.DisplayGridlines = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And pass it a *Worksheet* variable, not a `String`.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress")

TurnOffGridLines target:=ws
```

And it you just want to do this manually, *View* > *Gridlines* or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: Alt+W+V+G. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to turn them white, set the `.LineStyle` property of `Borders` to none.

`.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone`

If you actually want the bottom white:

`.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 2`

or

`.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)`

Comment: OP wants white borders.

Comment: Edited to reflect comment. I work almost exclusively in Word, and it's `wdWhite` almost always

Comment: @BigBen again, Word vestige. Also, he says he wants it to appear borderless. I suggested making it actually borderless. I can edit to give both options.

Comment: That *removes* the border -but the grid is still there. I understand "borderless" to mean no grid.

Comment: My second snippet colors the edge of the cell white, which is what I understand to be the question

Comment: `ColorIndex` depends on the current color palette. I wouldn't use that either tbh.

Comment: @bigben AGH. Happy now?

Comment: Well to be honest, `vbWhite` is equivalent to `RGB(255, 255, 255)` so we're kind of back to where we started.

Comment: @jclasley - I tried your suggestion but I am getting an error. See screengrab above.